Embedded Iframe content is not loading in IOS devices - safari
I have iframe content loading external source. my code is like this
<iframe title="xyz" allowtransparency = "true" marginheight="0"
  marginwidth ="0" class="investisIframe"
  src="https://irs.tools.investis.com/Clients/uk/bt/SharePriceLookup/Default.html?culture=en-GB"
  frameborder="0" id="001" width="100%" height="500">
</iframe>

Above code works fine in android and windows devices.  But not working in ios devices. Please help me to resolve this issue

I have tried clearing the cache still the same issue.
By adding timestamp at the end of url then also same issue.


How do you know the content isn't loaded?

Container looks empty

A container can look empty for several different reasons. Take a look at the Network tab of Dev Tools to see what is really loaded, and check also the console for errors.
